# Could channeling effects explain cold fusion?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, cold-fusion

Anomalous QED effects related to  [channeling effects](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(85)90021-3)   in  crystal lattices, could explain an enhanced fusion cross section, related to a wide class of fusion reactions.

Following   [Schwinger](https://www.infinite-energy.com/iemagazine/issue1/colfusthe.html)  , I consider the reaction:

proton + deuteron   = Helium-3 + lattice energy.

Could channelling  effects in the  Palladium lattice explain the alleged positive results of the original Pons-Fleischmann experiment? If not, because the energy range of the quantum systems involved is low (in the original Pons-Fleischmann experiments), could high energy protons and deuterons channeled through the Palladium lattice lead to enhanced fusion rates?

Comment: The big problem with "cold fusion" is that none of the claimed experiments reliably show the tell-tale sign of fusion: the production of energetic nuclear radiation. It doesn't matter how you get the fusion to occur - once it does, such radiation _must_ be released as the newly-formed nucleus relaxes to its ground state.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great difference between [QED](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/qed.html) and [QCD](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/color.html), and it is due to the form of the reaction. QED is long distance and the potentials go with 1/r, while QCD is short distance and bound within [fermi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femtometre) distances.

This allows QED quantum mechanical effects to cover whole lattices ( and in superconductivity kilometers) but it is not possible to have the same behavior for QCD interactions between the nucleons of a lattice, because the solutions are localized at the nuclei.So no analogy can work between the two scales, the interactions are radically different

Comment: Thank you for your answer @annav  . I must say, I am a fan , your feedback is always full of useful insight.  Related to my question (which is basically a  translation of Schwinger's model) , quantum tunneling  is the facilitator of the fusion process, and this can be modelled within QED.  That means that the crystal lattice plays an important role in this contex, even if the relevant spatial scales related to QCD and QED are different. .

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu  have a look my similar answer here where they talk of tunneling https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/493819/has-many-body-tunneling-at-the-level-of-nuclei-been-studied/493837#493837

Comment: "The two quantum mechanical systems ,nuclear and atomic, are not comparable.". Right, I am not challenging this statement. After quantum tunneling (QED level) those quantum systems are close enough so that the nuclear force (QCD) kicks in. That's  my point.

Comment: Overcoming  the Coulomb barrier (through quantum tunneling) is the issue here.  Once this  is done (through tunneling,  QED level)  the nuclear force  kicks  in. I don't  see the problem here  I might be missing  something.

Comment: Please let me know if I am missing something here.  @annav

Comment: The Coulomb barrier overcome when one is talking of an atomic latice depends on an effectively sincle  potential with periodic dependence  in space , because of the form of QED. The nuclei sitting in the atoms on a lattice do ot forman effective single potential  because  color forces do not get out of the bag of dimensions of fermi, so one cannot say that one effective potential that creates a barrier can be built up . Each nucleus is incoherent, as far as QCD goes, with its neighbors. One cannot build up one qcd quantum mechanical wavefunction.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html . Each nucleus is effectively  in an infinite potential well

Comment: Thank you for your correction @annav I edited my question, no reference to quantum tunneling. I also had a closer look at Schwinger's model, a solid state physics analysis of certain types of nuclear reactions in the crystal lattice. He noted the results are extremely sensitive to the actual values of a few parameters , a type of sensitivity that can only be seen when studying chaos theory. This could explain the reproducibility problem of the original Pons-Fleischmann experiments.

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu I am open minded as far as cold fusion goes.  We have to wait and see for experimental results that are consistently reproducible